# How do I make clickable HTML text that loads a <script>?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, src

Hello Im trying to insert some clickable text into my blog in which a popup

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.getresponse.com/view_webform_v2.js?u=BvFE6&webforms_id=2645901"></script>
```

will appear.  How do I do this correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to add script to the page:

```
X.onclick = function(){
    var myScript = document.createElement('script');
    mySript.src='...';
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If requirement does not permit to use jquery then you can also use javascript to append script on runtime using below code:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Append script on runtime</title>   
    <style type="text/css">
        #text-link {
            color: blue;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="blog-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pretium sodales turpis.
    <span id="text-link">fermentum lacinia</span> ligula. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">     
   window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById("text-link").addEventListener("click", addScript);

    function addScript(){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://app.getresponse.com/view_webform_v2.js?u=BvFE6&webforms_id=2645901';
        document.head.appendChild(script);

        // if wants to support IE < 9 then instead of document.head use 
        // document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
    }

   }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can further enhance the code to append it only once, if it already exists.

Answer (score -1):

```
<p class='appendScriptTag'> click me </p>

<script>

$('.appendScriptTag').on('click',function(){
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.src = "https://app.getresponse.com/view_webform_v2.js?u=BvFE6&webforms_id=2645901";
  $("head").append(s);
})

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use jQuery to append script on runtime using below code:

```js
$("<script>", {
    src: "https://app.getresponse.com/view_webform_v2.js?u=BvFE6&webforms_id=2645901",
    type: "text/javascript"
}).appendTo("body");
```

We can use same script on click on an element. Refer the code below for working example.

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Append script on runtime</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #text-link {
            color: blue;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="blog-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pretium sodales turpis.
    <span id="text-link">fermentum lacinia</span> ligula. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#text-link").on("click", function() {
            $("<script>", {
                src: "https://app.getresponse.com/view_webform_v2.js?u=BvFE6&webforms_id=2645901",
                type: "text/javascript"
            }).appendTo("body");
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you know they're using jquery?